# Unable to make a Core Data transient attribute private

Tags: objective-c, core-data, private, transient

I have a Core Data entity `Series` with a transient attr `indexCurrent`. When outside classes access `indexCurrent`, I want them to send in an arg that can be used to check whether `indexCurrent`’s value needs to be updated before returning it. Therefore, I have declared `indexCurrent` as a private variable, and allow outside access to it only through that special method with an arg.

But although the compiler issues "method not found" warnings, it allows outside classes to call both `indexCurrent` and `setindexCurrent:`, and this faulty code executes with complete success.

Here is the `Series` interface:

```
@interface Series : NSManagedObject {
@private
NSNumber *indexCurrent;  
}
```

`indexCurrent` is not propertized, is not declared as dynamic in the implementation file, and I have not written `indexCurrent` or `setindexCurrent:` accessors.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make `indexCurrent` private?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@dynamic doesn't cause any code to be generated. Core Data generates the code for property accessors whether or not you use @dynamic. @dynamic just informs the compiler that code will be generated, so it doesn't need to warn about missing methods. That's why you get warnings but no runtime errors.

The @private on the instance variable doesn't do much. The default is @protected, which means outside classes can't access it anyway, only the class itself and subclasses. In any case, the default Core Data accessors don't use instance variables.

I'm not sure how to do what you want.

Comment: I'll consider the upshot to be that that is no such thing as private managed-object attributes, and I will just have to rely on the absence of dot-syntax (which won't work without the @property line) to enforce  my design. Thanks for your explanations, which make for a nice anatomy lesson on Core Data.

Comment: Keep in mind, the whole concept of public protected and private is not really an Objective-C design pattern.  It exists but I would not rely on it.  The markers are more there for the human to read and say "oh I shouldn't touch that". The compiler is not going to get in your way if you ignore that warning.